# What is the best way to dynamically scale styles in React Native Web on window resize?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, react-native-web

I am trying to create a responsive React Native Web app, that also supports iOS and Android.

What I am finding is that there seems to be no way to dynamically resize based on a changing window size.

I want to have some cards resize upon window resize.

Here's my styles:

```
MainStyles = StyleSheet.create(
    {
        card: {
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            alignSelf: "flex-end",
            marginBottom: scale(10),
            marginLeft: scale(10),
            marginRight: scale(10),
            shadowColor: colorBlack,
            shadowOffset: {
                width: 4,
                height: 4,
            },
            shadowOpacity: 0.53,
            shadowRadius: scale(3.62),
            elevation: 4,
            alignSelf: "flex-end", 
        }
    }
```

However, if I try to add something like this:

```
const window = Dimensions.get("window");

const width_proportion = (window.width * .20);
const height_proportion = (window.height * .20);
```

It just sets a static value in the stylesheet, which doesn't update.

I have to actually do this inside my component, which feels a bit too coupled:

```
class Card extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            cardSize: (Dimensions.get("window").width * .2)
        }
    }

componentDidMount() {
    if(window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize)
        }
}

resize = () => {
    // Going for a square size, hence using width for both height/width.
    const window = Dimensions.get("window");
    this.setState({cardSize: (window.width * .2)})
     this.forceUpdate()
   }

render() {
return(
<View style={[MainStyles.card, { width: this.state.cardSize, height: this.state.cardSize}]}>
...
</View>
     );
   }
}
```

Is there a cleaner way that lets me add dynamic styles to React Native Web without needing to generate the styles directly in the component? All I want is for my styles to update on window resize dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Its always good to have our own codebase but if you looking for easy solutions then you can try this plugin

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-screen
```

They have provided some cool features or else there are multiple plugins available too.

> Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Biggest annoyance here is that it is per component. I'd like a universal resize, much like regular web development has.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to just use flex:
Layout with Flexbox docs https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox

This way you can create a view with padding. It will automatically resize.

```
<View style={{flex: 1, padding: 15}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach, which lets you use different layouts for different window width/height ratios:

https://github.com/MehmetKaplan/react-native-animated-layout